# Is there a single "analytics/marketing" SDK solution for mobile apps?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, urbanairship.com, testflight, apptentive

I hope this is not off topic for StackOverflow since it is not just software development related but also marketing. But I guess this problem is something we developers are all confronted to.

To monitor and market our iOS app, we use a bunch of third party SDKs:

- Google Analytics to understand what's happening
- a push notification system (e.g. Urban Airship)
- a "smart" review prompting engine (e.g. Apptentive)
- a testing / crash reporting system (e.g. Testflight)
- should you want to run app installs ads, you also need the FB SDK, an SDK to track Twitter conversions, etc.
- you may also want to track where other installs come from via something like Tapstream.

So we are already running more than 6 3rd party SDKs in our app, and it does not feel right:

- each of them will do some kind of hand shake every time the app is opened
- it's as many potential issues
- each of them will have a different web interface

Is there a way to optimise all this, i.e. to have just one SDK doing most things? Or does someone know of a lib to wrap all this stuff under one lib for instance?

Answer (score 1):

There is no getting around a few of these. If you want to talk with FaceBook, Twitter, etc. You will need their SDK no matter the 3rd party SDK you choose.

You could actually write your own setup to track and deal with everything, but there are those that have done it before.

For example, [Parse](https://parse.com) will do:

- Analytics
- push notifications
- a "smart" review prompting engine (you can do this yourself by reviewing the analytics)
- crash reporting system
- it also uses FB SDK, Twitter SDK already to help with user logins where users my want to use their credentials from their sites on your app
- user login
- cloud database
- You could technically throw an "event" into the analytics to track how many folks are using your app that was installed from x store. However, this would require a different version of your app for each store. Sounds like an interesting idea none the less. Tapstreme and others are basically marketing though, not really something required to do something specific. You will need an SDK if they are tracking something specific themselves.
- one web interface

There are multiple systems built like this. they are called BaaS or Backend as a Service.

Hope this helps, Cheers

Comment: Thanks @AlienDev. I'll look at Parse. Thing is we don't need all the BaaS stuff since we are rolling our own. On your last point: I do find Tapstream very interesting. When someone installs your app, they can cross-reference the device ID and find which (custom) install link was originally clicked on this device. Say you write a blog post and add a custom install link. You will be able to know which users installed the app after reading the article. It's handy and I haven't found a simple way to do it otherwise.

Comment: I didn't realize it went that far out there. I'll have to look into it to. as far as the BaaS piece. Just because it is offered as one big package, doesn't mean you have to use every piece of it. It is the only "full package" I have found. you may have to do some more work on your end to get all the information the other guys give you, but in the end, it is one interface, one login, and one SDK.